# Java Spring Dependency Injection creates two beans, when there should just be one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to enable our application to use Springs Dependency Injection. For some reason, some classes get instantiated twice, which leads to an  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.
The ID of one Bean is just the simple class name, the other is the full name with a #0 at the end:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'FDDConnectionFactory' defined in file [W:\Projekte\ocp-ospe\ServiceGruppe\osplus.ocp.service.impl\target\classes\osplus\dynssee\ie\ocp\bs\services\fdd\FDDConnectionFactory.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'osplus.dynssee.ie.ocp.bs.services.fdd.FDDParameterResolver' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: FDDDefaultParameterResolver,osplus.dynssee.ie.ocp.bs.services.fdd.FDDDefaultParameterResolver#0

```
@Component
public class FDDDefaultParameterResolver implements FDDParameterResolver {
    private FremdsystemProviderProvider fremdsystemProviderProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    public FDDDefaultParameterResolver(FremdsystemProviderProvider fPP) {
        this.fremdsystemProviderProvider = fPP;
    }
    
    // Some methods
}

@Component
public class FDDConnectionFactory {
    @Autowired
    public FDDConnectionFactory(FDDParameterResolver fddParams) {
        this.fddParams = fddParams;
    }
}
```

I cut down the class to it's bare minimum, as you can see above. But weirdly enough, I'm unable to recreate another minimal example that exhibits the same behaviour. Some injections just work, others don't.
Anybody got some ideas what might be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: can you put out `FDDDefaultParameterResolve`?

Comment: Your code needs two objects. Hence two instances.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why would I need two instances? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Your code does.  No idea why.

Comment: Maybe check whether you have `@Bean FDDParameterResolver someMethod()` defined anywhere in `@Configuration` classes. I also wonder if you have any other than `FDDDefaultParameterResolver` `FDDParameterResolver` implementations.

Comment: There is no second implementation of `FDDParameterResolver`, I deleted it to track down the issue. Neither is there a `@Bean FDDParameterResolver method()`, I just started to transition to DI.
I also don't have a `@Configuration` class, I just have a `<context:component-scan>` in an XML Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issues was bound to my company's framework, where they already perform some kind of component-scan on specific packages.